# Clearing ExtJS combobox input field

Tags: input, extjs, combobox, expand

I have an Ext.form.ComboBox with the following properties:

```
fieldLabel: 'Regiune',
valueField: 'id',
displayField: 'reg',
id: 'cbRegR',
typeAhead: true,
store: new Ext.data.JsonStore({...}),
mode: 'local',
emptyText: '',
listeners:{...}
```

The problem is that I have to manually delete the combobox' input field after selecting a value from the dropdown list to view all the list items. The matter is the list displays only the items that begin with letters in input field.

How can I clear the input field on expanding dropdown list? I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
listeners: { 'expand': function() { cbRegR.clearValue(); } }
```

Seems to be easy but it ain't so for me.. Any bright ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: o-kay, how can I mark my question as SOLVED?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the config property to your combobox

```
triggerAction: 'all'
```

might do the trick, without the need to register an expand event handler or clearing the combobox's value

Comment: yes it DID :) is there a risk when setting triggerAction 'all'?

Comment: the docs [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.form.ComboBox) says that if `triggerAction` is set to "all" the value of the `allQuery` option is used to query the data - by default, this is "" so all data is returned.

Comment: more appropriate [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-cfg-triggerAction) url  of @user69820

Answer (score 1):

It is an intrinsic behaviour of Ext JS ComboBox-es to filter the list items based on the field value, as you already know.

You could perceivably override the expand() method, making additions to clear out the value before it renders the list. EG:

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.ComboBox, {

    expand : function(){
        if(this.isExpanded() || !this.hasFocus){
            return;
        }
        //ADDITIONS HERE:
        this.clearValue();
        this.doQuery("", true);
        //ADDITIONS END HERE

        if(this.title || this.pageSize){
            this.assetHeight = 0;
            if(this.title){
                this.assetHeight += this.header.getHeight();
            }
            if(this.pageSize){
                this.assetHeight += this.footer.getHeight();
            }
        }

        if(this.bufferSize){
            this.doResize(this.bufferSize);
            delete this.bufferSize;
        }
        this.list.alignTo.apply(this.list, [this.el].concat(this.listAlign));

        // zindex can change, re-check it and set it if necessary
        this.list.setZIndex(this.getZIndex());
        this.list.show();
        if(Ext.isGecko2){
            this.innerList.setOverflow('auto'); // necessary for FF 2.0/Mac
        }
        this.mon(Ext.getDoc(), {
            scope: this,
            mousewheel: this.collapseIf,
            mousedown: this.collapseIf
        });
        this.fireEvent('expand', this);
    }

});
```

Comment: mm-hmm. so i need to write it one time somewhere on the top of page, right?

Comment: Personally I save overrides into their own JS file and call them into the page right after calling in the ext scripts. They'll be applied before anything else happens then.

Comment: PS: Be warned, an override like the example above will be applied to ALL ComboBoxes. If this isn't desired behaviour then you might want to first extend ComboBox to make your own version, then override the expand function on your own extension.

Answer (score 0):

The expand event is the good one but you have to be careful about the scope.

```
listeners: {
 'expand': function() {
    cbRegR.clearValue(); 
 },
 scope:this
}
```

Does setting the scope helps?

Comment: setting the scope property doesn't let the data to populate the combobox, or rather the combobox simply doesn't display data list on expand

Answer (score 0):

Using `cbRegR` won't work, because it's an undefined variable. Either use

```
listeners: { 'expand': function() { Ext.getCmp('cbRegR').clearValue(); } }
```

or, a more sophisticated approach:

```
listeners: { 'expand': function(self) { self.clearValue(); } }
```

Comment: cbRegR is defined as cbReg = new Ext.form.ComboBox, it's the object i'm working with